# Lua new table from smaller table

Tags: lua, lua-table

Struggling with a specific Lua table problem, extracting values from a smaller table to set on/off switches for a longer table.

I have an iterator:

```
for i = 0,11 do
some things
end
```

Inside the iterator with length 12 I wish to extract values from a table that might look like this (always <= iterator length):

`t = {0,2,4,6,8,10}`

and generate a new table with the iterator so that if index i = t value insert 1 else insert 0. That is, the new table would look like this:

`newTable = {1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0}`

Help?

Answer (score 1):

```lua
t = {0,2,4,6,8,10}
newTable = {}

for i = 0, 11 do
    newTable[i] = 0
end -- Set the entire new table to 0's

for _, v in ipairs(t) do
    newTable[v] = 1
end -- Loop through t, replace the 0's in new table with a 1 where newTable[v]
```

Comment: `ipairs` will skip the 0th entry. `pairs` won't.

Comment: ... but in the code above, `ipairs` is applied to `t`, not to `newTable`, so it's fine.

Comment: pairs was the right answer for me in context, thanks again